# extracting text between two words in a text file, discarding all the rest in shell script

Tags: shell, sed

I have a file of the form:

```
    blablabla var="value_var1" blabla
    blablabla var="value_var2" blabla
```

and so on. I would like to obtain a text file like:

```
    value_var1
    value_var2
    ...
```

Any ideas?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You could try this cut command:

```
cut -d \" -f 2 filename
```

or:

```
grep -oP '"\K[^" ]*' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below sed command,

```
sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/' infile > outfile
```

If you want to get the preceeding spaces also then use the below regex.

```
sed 's/^\( *\).*"\(.*\)".*/\1\2/g' infile > outfile
```

Answer (score 0):

The perl variant

- will match only *var="**something**"* and not *var2="other"*
- will match multiple occurences in the line

```
perl -nE 'say $1 while m/\bvar\s*=\s*"(.*?)"/g'
```

from the next input

```
blabl somevar="some" abla var="value_var1" blabla var = "value2" blabal
blablabla var="value_var2" blabla
```

produces

```
value_var1
value2
value_var2
```

Get teh value from any *something="**value**"* the next grep will work

```
grep -oP '=\s*"\K(.*?)(?=")'
```

for the same input prints

```
some
value_var1
value2
value_var2
```

Answer (score 0):

With `sed` you can remove the text up to the first `"` and after the second `"` with:

```
sed -e 's/.*"//;s/".*//' < infile > outfile
```

This is a bit more complicated than the `cut` version but it might be easier to fix, if it process certain lines in an inappropriate manner.